Spring @Autowired in mapped object from Jackson ObjectMapper
Is there a way to get @Autowired Objects initialized properly inside a newly created Object that came from objectMapper.readValue()?
BaseEventInfo eventInfo = objectMapper.readValue(eventJson, BaseEventInfo.class);
eventInfo.parseEvent();

@Component
public class BaseEventInfo{
    @Autowired
    SomeObject someObject;

    String mappedField;
    
    public void parseEvent(){
        someObject.doSomething() <- null pointer :(
    }

    public String getMappedField() {
        return mappedField;
    }

    public void setMappedField(String mappedField) {
       this.mappedField = mappedField;
    }
}

I know I could pass in the values, but I would rather not to keep the parseEvent method generic.

why do you even have an object that is being sent/read from a JSON as a component? This doesn't make sense to start with. Can you explain why you need that? This looks like an XYProblem by the way.

@JorgeCampos I have json coming in through an api that can be mapped to a variety of different objects. I need to parse these objects into our database through a complex mapping.
I am having jackson put the data into a class based on the type of json coming in. I would like this newly created Object to be able to parse itself.

That's the wrong approach for it. The parsing should be a responsibility of your application not the class you are passing in.

The short answer is, no, this is not possible.  Components are maintained by the framework.  Make your BaseEventInfo a POJO without SomeObject, whatever you're doing in parseEvent, add a method in SomeObject that takes a BaseEventInfo and does this work

It seems like I will have to make a new class that takes in a variety of different event types in parse methods and itself will be a component so then all the autowiring will work.

In short, no. Even though BaseEventInfo is a Spring-managed bean (assuming proper component scan) you're instantiating another instance using Jackson that is separate/different from the instance created by Spring.  The instance created by Jackson is not managed by Spring.  In other words it's as if you wrote:
BaseEventInfo eventInfo = new BaseEventInfo();

Spring would not inject SomeObject into that either.

Yeah its what I thought, but I was hoping there was some spring injector I could get access to.

@coloradoman Make BaseEventInfo prototype-scoped and request a new one from Spring as needed.  See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes

I solved this by making the Object jackson also contain a factory like method that returns a different object and uses ApplicationContext to have the factory create the new object how it needs to.
Here is an example
@Autowired
ApplicationContext ctx;

BaseEventInfo eventInfo = objectMapper.readValue(eventJson, JacksonInObject.class);
EventParser parser = eventInfo.getParser(ctx);
parser.parse();


@Component
public class JacksonInObject implements BaseEventInfo { //BaseEventInfo contains getParser stub
  String mappedField;

  @Override
  public EventParser getParser(ApplicationContext ctx) {
      return new SpecificEventParser(ctx,this);
  }
}


public class SpecificEventParser implements EventParser { //EventParser contains parse stub
  SomeObject someObject;
  JacksonInObject jacksonInObject

  public SpecificEventParser(ApplicationContext ctx, JacksonInObject jacksonInObject){
    //Inject it here finally
    someObject= ctx.getBean(SomeObject.class);
    this.jacksonInObject = jacksonInObject;
  }

  parse(){
     someObject.doSomething();
     ...
  }
}

